# Android app does not order the sites on "Your Sites" in a correct way

Tags: bug, android-app, communities-list

When reorder the "Your Sites" list on the Android app, the list doesn't get refreshed accordingly. Sites are shown in correct order on computer but not in Android app.

My phone model is HTC One, Android 4.2.2, app version 1.0.31

Steps to reproduce problem:

1. Pull the left panel.
2. Click on "edit" next to the "Your sites" label.
3. Reorder your sites.
4. Press back button to go back.
5. Check if the ordering of your sites on the left panel are updated.

In my experience, sites are always listed by the time of pinning. It doesn't change when I manually reorder them.

I believe the reason why no one could reproduce this problem is because the problem occurs only if you add **more than 10 sites**.

I first thought that the app does not refresh the list but later I found out that there could be a problem in the ordering algorithm because it adds the 11th, 12th, 13th, etc. item *right after the first item*. And if you add more than 20 sites, it puts 21st, 22nd, etc *under the second item* on the actual list.

Comment: No repro on Moto G, Android 4.4.2, App 1.0.31

Comment: Oh, it is interesting. It seems only I have this problem on my device. I tried logging out and logging back in to check if this was a one time issue. But the problem remains to exist.

Comment: Hmm no repro on my Nexus 5, Android 4.4.2 either. I'll see if I can find a HTC One to try on.

Comment: No one interested?